# How to get email Receipient's profile photo/icon by using java mail?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, email

I am using "com.google.code.javax.mail" package in Java to retrive emails from Gmail Account.

```
import com.google.code.javax.mail.*;

            String[] folders = {"INBOX","[Gmail]/Sent Mail"};  

            for(String fd:folders) {
                 String folder  = fd;
                  Folder folder1 = store.getFolder(folder);
                  if(!folder1.isOpen()) 
                  folder1.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

                  Message[] messages = folder1.getMessages();
                  for (int i = ex_mail_count;i<msgCount; i++) {

                      Message message = messages[i];
                      String subject = message.getSubject();

                  }
            }
```

The mails and headers are listed successfully. But I want to get and display Receipients photo with their email content using java. So how to get Receipient's profile photo? Here I have attached sample Gmail UI look like same as my project.

[image: Sample mail UI]

Pls help me.

Comment: I don't know how to do it, but I know the answer isn't JavaMail.  You'll need to use some Gmail or Google specific API.

Comment: Yes Bill. We can get only our mail photo by using GoogleAPI. But not able to get others mail photo.